# Listview with button OnItemClickListener is not calling

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I create a custom `listview` with a `TextView` and 2 `ImageButton`. But `onitemclicklistner` is not calling. Here is my code

```
    police_station_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.police_station_listView_xml);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.coustome_listview, R.id.district_listview_xml1, police_station_name);
    PSAdapter = new Police_Station_Adapter(this);
    police_station_list.setAdapter(PSAdapter);

    police_station_list.setOnItemClickListener(PSAdapter);
```

Here is my custom `ArrayAdapter` class:

```
public class Police_Station_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnItemClickListener{
Context context;

public Police_Station_Adapter(Context context) {
    //super(context, R.layout.police_station_listview, R.id.police_station_listView_textView, police_station_name);
    super(context, R.layout.police_station_listview, police_station_name);
    this.context = context;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
    ImageButton mobile, phone;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.police_station_listView_textView);
        mobile = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.police_station_listView_imageButton_mobile);
        phone = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.police_station_listView_imageButton_phone);
    }
}

ViewHolder holder;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.police_station_listview, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(v);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv.setText(police_station_name[position]);


    holder.mobile.setTag(position);

    holder.mobile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Message(context, police_station_name[(Integer) v.getTag()]+" button", 500);
        }
    });


    return v;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
    new Message(context, "Item Clicked", 500); //Toast message

}
```

}

Here is the custom `ListView` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/police_station_listView_textView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/police_station_listView_imageButton_mobile"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mobile_icon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/police_station_listView_imageButton_phone"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/telephone_icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

it's seems like i can add `onClikcListner` for textview but it doesn't show any pressed animation. It may not be the appropriate solution. I need the proper way to `setOnItemClickListner`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set *OnItemClickListener* in your Activity. then change this

```
 police_station_list.setOnItemClickListener(PSAdapter); to 
 police_station_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Remove implementation of *OnItemClickListener* from adapter. 
[Check this tutorial](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

add this attribute to imageButton:

```
 android:focusable="false"
```